# Spring Boot - Different URI encoding for different HTTP requests

Tags: java, spring, encoding, utf-8, latin1

My question is, it is possible to use different URI encoding for different HTTP requests in a single Spring Boot application?

Why I ask this question: My existing Spring Boot Application is using UTF8 so far. Now it have to handle a HTTP request from an external service, where I can't choose the encoding. The request parameters may contain german umlauts which are Latin1 encoded and will be misinterpreted now with UTF8. I added `server.tomcat.uri-encoding=Cp1252` to the application.properties file which solved my problem with this single request but I want to keep UTF8 as URI encoding in all my other requests. Is this somehow possible?

Comment: Have a look at this post [spring-boot-uri-encoding](https://dddpaul.github.io/blog/2015/12/21/spring-boot-uri-encoding/). It might give you a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks, I will check that out!